# mongodb collection count returns 1000 but should be higher

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm bulk importing several million records into mongodb but while checking the number of documents it stays at 1000.

```
> db.records.count()
1000
> db.records.distinct('hash').length
1000
```

However my script thinks it has inserted 512K (and increasing) records without any exceptions being thrown (I'm using pymongo). Is there an implicit maximum size for a collection?

#### Update: contents of `db.records.stats()`

```
> db.records.stats()
{
    "ns" : "test2.records",
    "count" : 2000,
    "size" : 152012,
    "avgObjSize" : 76.006,
    "storageSize" : 696320,
    "numExtents" : 4,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "lastExtentSize" : 524288,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "flags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 73584,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 73584
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.records.count()
2000
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `db.records.stats()`?

Comment: Updated - count increased to 2000, but from that info it seems like it  is storing at least some of the records.

Comment: Can you post the details of your script which is inserting the data? Are you using safe=True on your inserts?

Comment: make sure you're importing those records within safemode. What mostlikely causes your problem is that you're trying to use duplicate ids. Without safe mode you're missing those exceptions and think that its working, while its not.

Comment: You should post the code you're using to do the inserts.